# Automatically Refresh a IRR based on a Checkbox in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 4.2.

Now, I have an Oracle APEX page that has an Interactive Report Region (IRR) and what I am attempting to do, is to add a automatic report refresh mechanism with a checkbox that will be used to activate/de-activate the report refresh.

Basically, when the page initially loads, I would like to default the checkbox to being checked (i.e. 'Y') which would initiate say an automatic 10 second refresh of the IRR, at the same time, maintaining the checkbox value of "checked" - perhaps this will need to be in a different region, so when the automatic refresh occurs, the checkbox continues to maintain state of "checked" and only the IRR refreshes, with any new rows/values that may have been added/changed.

At the same time, I would also like to de-activate the automatic 10 second IRR refresh by unchecking the checkbox, which would no longer perform a report refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread in the Oracle APEX forums that I must have missed relating to my post:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2461953

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please copy below code and paste accorfingly.

Page attributes, Javascript, Function and Global Variable Declaration

var gtReloadPage;

"autorefresh" dynamic action

2 true actions:

Execute PLSQL code

null;

Page Items to Submit : P1_CHECK_BOX

Fire on page load: CHECKED
Execute javascript code

alert('ok - setting timeout');
gtReloadPage = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",8000);

Fire on page load: CHECKED

2 false actions:

Execute PLSQL code

null;

Page Items to Submit : P1_CHECK_BOX

Fire on page load: UNCHECKED
Execute javascript code

clearTimeout(gtReloadPage);
alert("Timeout has been removed!");

Fire on page load: UNCHECKED